# Search function returns the wrong count

Tags: c

I have a search function which I know is the problem but cannot seem to fix it. 
I am using the function for searching in my child processes.

This is the test file I am using

> Associate Professor of key2 Computer Science Patrick Eugster is the recipient of a sponsored research award key2 Google for his project Geo-Distributed Big Data Processing, which is joint work with Ph.D. students Chamikara Jayalath and Julian Stephe 23456 key1 Several Computer Science faculty and staff members were recognized at the Purdue University College of Science's annual Faculty and Staff Awards Program on February 21, 2013. key2 Several Computer Science faculty and staff members were recognized at the Purdue University College of Science's annual Faculty key Staff Awards Program on February 21, 2013. key1 key1 key1 Several Computer Science faculty and staff recognized at the Purdue

I should get the result at

```
key1: 4
key2: 3
```

but I get my result as

```
key1: 4
key2: 1
```

Where am I going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
int search(FILE *file, char *key, int bufferSize, long int start)
{
    int wordCtr = 0;
    int buffer = 0;
    if ( file != NULL )
    {
        printf("test 1 at position %ld in file\n", ftell(file));
        fseek(file, start, SEEK_SET);
        int ch, word = 0;
        char currentWord[MAX_WORD_LEN];
        int i = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF && counter < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE-1)
        {
            counter++;
            if (isspace(ch)|| ch =='\n' || ch =='\t' && (buffer++ < bufferSize))
            {
                if(word)
                {
                    word = 0;
                    currentWord[i++] = '\0';
                    i = 0;
                    if(!strcmp(currentWord, key))
                    {
                        wordCtr++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                word = 1;
                currentWord[i++]=ch;
            }
        }
    }
    return wordCtr;
}
```

Please let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: You suspect a problem with the number you have set as the buffer size. 
Do I need to specify the buffer size to read one by one? isspace is true that ('\n', '\t')

Comment: Do **not** destroy your question.  I've rolled back your edit for you.

Comment: did u try using a debugger

Answer (score 1):

I did not follow all your code, but it could be this:

```
if (isspace(ch)|| ch =='\n' || ch =='\t' && (buffer++ < bufferSize))
```

the tests `ch =='\t' && (buffer++ < bufferSize)` are tied together. is that really what you want? I think you meant

```
if ((isspace(ch)|| ch =='\n' || ch =='\t') && (buffer++ < bufferSize))
```

Comment: no that is not the case. I have tested it that way before posting it. But that is a better way to code no doubt.

Comment: it is not "better way to code", as these versions have completely different semantics. one is correct, one is not. I'll try to look for other problems, anyway.

Comment: Note that `isspace()` checks for `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, `'\f'`, `'\v'`, `'\r'` so the `||` terms are redundant.  The `isblank()` function checks for `' '` and `'\t'`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) based on your code.  I've simplified the interface to the search function; it no longer takes the buffer size or start offset that your original code took.  The original code didn't really use them very much anyway.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_WORD_LEN = 64 };

static
int search(FILE *file, char *key)
{
    int wordCtr = 0;
    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_SET);
    int ch, word = 0;
    char currentWord[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF && i < MAX_WORD_LEN-1)
    {
        if (isspace(ch))
        {
            if (word)
            {
                word = 0;
                currentWord[i] = '\0';
                i = 0;
                //printf("compare: [[%s]] vs [[%s]]\n", key, currentWord);
                if (strcmp(currentWord, key) == 0)
                    wordCtr++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            word = 1;
            currentWord[i++] = ch;
        }
    }
    return wordCtr;
}

static void print_search(FILE *fp, char *key)
{
    int n = search(fp, key);
    printf("%s: %d\n", key, n);
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("text", "r");
    if (fp != 0)
    {
        print_search(fp, "key1");
        print_search(fp, "key2");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Given the input text in the question, the output is as expected:

```
key1: 4
key2: 3
```

Your main problems were with the buffer size and the number of different ways you were counting the number of characters in a word.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the search method so you'll probably have to update with some context on how you're using it.
Random aside, the increment in this code is redundant:

```
currentWord[i++] = '\0';
i = 0
```